# PEP8 and base64 strings

Tags: python, pep8

The project I'm working on runs a linting check before validating the build. The linter checks PEP8 compliance among other things. I have a base64 string, that's about 5,000 characters long (it's a file converted into a base64 string), and so of course, the linter doesn't like it.

It seems to me like it would be really dumb to just split the string into 60+ lines just to make it PEP8 compliant.

Having the file as a physical file and reading it on the fly isn't really an option for the context. Reading a file from an external source isn't an option either.

Edit: The PEP8 compliance check is done with Flake8

Looking for suggestions on how to go about this.

Comment: "It seems to me like it would be really dumb to just split the string into 60+ lines just to make it PEP8 compliant." — Why?  If you want to be PEP 8 compliant, and putting the string outside the source code isn't an option, splitting the string up is pretty much your only option.

Comment: Agreed with @jwodder, assuming this is a string that won't be changing often (which I assume is the case since the string is not in an external file).  Splitting the string into lines should take no more than 30 seconds with a decent editor.

Comment: @Verv I suppose there is also an argument for adding `# nopep8`/`# noqa` at the end of the line if your linter supports it.

Comment: @0x5453 exactly the kind of alternative I was looking for, I'll look into this and see if it is indeed supported, thanks.

Comment: @Verv Could you use a triple-quote string literal to avoid splitting the lines? Would the linter complain about the length even in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)**

PEP8 is a style guide, not a rulebook. There are instances where it is best to ignore PEP8. Don't sacrifice code clarity for the sake of compliance. Is avoiding a single linter warning better than forcing your code into 60 lines and dealing with all the line breaks?

> It seems to me like it would be really dumb to just split the string into 60+ lines just to make it PEP8 compliant.

It is.

Depending on your linter, you may be able to put `# noqa` at the end of the offending line in order for it to ignore the PEP8 non-compliance. Check your linter documentation to see what it offers in this regard.